# How could you sort string words in low level?

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting

Of course there are handy library functions for all kind of languages to sort strings out. However I am interested in to know the low level details of string sorting. Mt naive belief is to use ASCII values of strings to convert the problem into numerical sorting. However, if the string word are larger than a single character then the thing is little complicated for me. What is the state of art sorting approach for multi-character sorting ?

Comment: All this is highly culture dependent, there are alphabets that contain the same characters but put them in a different order. This, just like dates is something best left alone. Also not using Unicode is racist :)

Comment: If your string is "larger than a single character", the obvious solution is to look at their *next* character. The same as sorting numerically: `10 = 11` and `10 = 101` are both false.

Comment: Are you interested in sorting strings for human usage e.g. for a dictionary or just sorting so that they are in an order useful for a computer algorithm? In other words, is your focus a) on how to impose an ordering on strings or b) on the sorting with an order already given?

Answer (score 2):

Strings are typically just sorted with a [comparison-based sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), such as [quick-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_sort) or [merge-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) (I know of a few libraries that does this, and I'd assume most would, although there can certainly be exceptions).

But you could indeed convert your string to a numeric value and use a [distribution sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Distribution_sort), such as counting-, bucket- or radix-sort, instead.

But there's no [silver bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bullet#Idiomatic_usage) here - the best solution will largely depend on the scenario - it's really just something you have to benchmark with the sorting implementations you're using, on the system you're working, with your typical data.

Answer (score 1):

Naive sorting of ASCII strings is naive because it basically treats the strings as numbers written in base-128 or base-256. Dictionaries are meant for human usage and sort strings according to more complex criteria.

A pretty elaborate example is the ['Unicode Technical Standard #10' - Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/).

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply [leaving a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the question instead of posting an answer.